# How to fetch multiple data from database in php using JSON in Android

Tags: php, android, json

It is showing just one value like ram@gmail.com or ram

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
code = (json.getInt("success"));
if (code ==1) {
    JSONArray user=json.getJSONArray("user");
    JSONObject product = user.getJSONObject(0);

    email1.setText(product.optString("email"));
    name1.setText(product.optString("name"));

    //nid.setText(product.getString("name"));
    Log.v("email",email1.toString());

    Toast.makeText(context,"Data successfully inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("msg", "Data Successfully Inserted");
    //Data Successfully Inserted
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Data are not successfully inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Data Not Inserted
}
```

Comment: I think your question is a little unclear. What's exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
 for (int i=0; i < user.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject product = user.getJSONObject(i);
           // product.optString("email")
           // product.optString("name")
        } catch (JSONException e) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to know how to fetch multiple data from database in android

Comment: means more than two fields

Comment: You can display multiple field depends upon the response of the JSON string. Do you have already a code to retrieve values in database to PHP in JSON format?

Comment: yes i have a code to retrieve values in database to php in json format

Comment: If the return JSON string in PHP has multiple values, then the solution will be is to loop the JSON Array.

Comment: this  code = (json.getInt("success")); email1.setText(product.optString("email"));  two are working but   this name1.setText(product.optString("name")); is not workig